# overflow:hidden on body causes document repaint mid-transition of another element in Safari

Tags: html, css

I have a layout that when an element is clicked, it expands and opens a modal
dialog. When it's clicked a `position:fixed` clone is appended to the body with the same position properties so that it appears in the same position as the original element. The clone then expands to fill the page to act as a dialog box.

A `noscroll` class is added to the body

```
.noscroll {
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: none; 
    position: relative;
}
```

This is where the problem starts to happen. When the clone element is in the middle of transitioning its position properties, a document repaint happens causing the transition to freeze and then continue when the repaint is over.

This only happens in Safari for some reason. Here's a screenshot of the timelines
to show what I mean

[image]

When I don't add the noscroll class, this doesn't happen. This is driving me crazy, I've tried everything and this keeps happening.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue today and the solution was to resize all of the images on my page.

For me, the huge green layout event actually wasn't layout or paint but composite. I understand this phase to be when the browser actually draws everything to the screen.

This was (I think) because all of the images on the page were way too big for the size they were being displayed at; ~14mb for images that were at most 300px wide. Resizing all of my images to a more appropriate 300x400 got rid of this issue completely. It makes sense that a bunch of huge images being hidden and shown would be really hard for the browser to draw. Still at a complete loss as to why this problem is triggered by `overflow: hidden`, and on Safari only.